# kdb - run function in different processes

Tags: kdb

I want the master q process to spin up slave processes give each slave process a function to execute on a list of inputs. For each atomic input the function will download some data (executing a remote function on a server over IPC using a server handle) and simply save the output table as a csv to disk.

```
srv:hopen `:server:port:user:pass
f:{[names;serverhandle]
      {[name;serverhandle]
        0N!"Processing ",string name;
        r:serverhandle(`.remotefunc;name);
        savelocation:"tmp/";
        (`$savelocation,(string name),".csv") 0: csv 0: r;
      }[;serverhandle] each names
  }[;srv];
```

I am starting 3 q slave processes:

```
handles:`u#`int$();
.z.pd:{n:abs system"s";$[n=count handles;handles;[hclose each handles;:handles::`u#hopen each mainport+1+til n]]}; 
.z.pc:{handles::`u#handles except x;}; 
startQs:{{value"\\q -p ",string[x]," -slave ",string[x-mainport]}each p:(value"\\p")+1+ til abs system"s"};

startQs[]; / starts slave q processes
.z.pd[];   / populates handles of slave q processes
```

and then I am trying to execute `f` for an equal-sized batch of `names` on each of the slave processes.

```
neg[handles] @' (f),/:enlist each (3;0N) # `vincent`mia`jules`marsellus`butch`jimmie`honey;
```

so the
- first slave process executes `f` on `` `vincent`mia`jules ``
- second slave process executes `f` on `` `marsellus`butch`jimmie ``
- third slave process executes `f` on `` `honey ``

but when I start the whole script `q name-dl.q -s 3 -p 5012` nothing happens (no files are downloaded). When I execute `f` manually on the **master** process, it works (e.g. `` f[`vincent] ``)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to this approach could be to make use of [`peach`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-parallel). If you start up you process with slaves you could then run:

```
f peach (3;0N) # `vincent`mia`jules`marsellus`butch`jimmie`honey
```

Which should run each command on a slave process.

Comment: I have tried that already, the data definitely gets retrieved (i.e. `r` in function `f` get populated) and if I return something from the function (like `ok) it's definitely there but it just doesnt write to disk :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but it works on linux.

On Windows, I tried to change the savelocation in `f` to windows path (with `\\` instead of `/`) but that didnt help either